# intel pin: detection of `malloc` two times, when used with a default tool

Tags: c++, c, x86, profiling, intel-pin

I used a pin tool posted on intel's official [Manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/index.html):

> ```
> #include "pin.H"
> #include <iostream>
> #include <fstream>
>
> /* ===================================================================== */
> /* Names of malloc and free */
> /* ===================================================================== */
> #if defined(TARGET_MAC)
> #define MALLOC "_malloc"
> #define FREE "_free"
> #else
> #define MALLOC "malloc"
> #define FREE "free"
> #endif
>
> /* ===================================================================== */
> /* Global Variables */
> /* ===================================================================== */
>
> std::ofstream TraceFile;
>
> /* ===================================================================== */
> /* Commandline Switches */
> /* ===================================================================== */
>
> KNOB<string> KnobOutputFile(KNOB_MODE_WRITEONCE, "pintool",
>     "o", "malloctrace.out", "specify trace file name");
>
> /* ===================================================================== */
>
>
> /* ===================================================================== */
> /* Analysis routines                                                     */
> /* ===================================================================== */
>
> VOID Arg1Before(CHAR * name, ADDRINT size)
> {
>     TraceFile << name << "(" << size << ")" << endl;
> }
>
> VOID MallocAfter(ADDRINT ret)
> {
>     TraceFile << "  returns " << ret << endl;
> }
>
>
> /* ===================================================================== */
> /* Instrumentation routines                                              */
> /* ===================================================================== */
>
> VOID Image(IMG img, VOID *v)
> {
>     // Instrument the malloc() and free() functions.  Print the input argument
>     // of each malloc() or free(), and the return value of malloc().
>     //
>     //  Find the malloc() function.
>     RTN mallocRtn = RTN_FindByName(img, MALLOC);
>     if (RTN_Valid(mallocRtn))
>     {
>         RTN_Open(mallocRtn);
>
>         // Instrument malloc() to print the input argument value and the return value.
>         RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)Arg1Before,
>                        IARG_ADDRINT, MALLOC,
>                        IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0,
>                        IARG_END);
>         RTN_InsertCall(mallocRtn, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)MallocAfter,
>                        IARG_FUNCRET_EXITPOINT_VALUE, IARG_END);
>
>         RTN_Close(mallocRtn);
>     }
>
>     // Find the free() function.
>     RTN freeRtn = RTN_FindByName(img, FREE);
>     if (RTN_Valid(freeRtn))
>     {
>         RTN_Open(freeRtn);
>         // Instrument free() to print the input argument value.
>         RTN_InsertCall(freeRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)Arg1Before,
>                        IARG_ADDRINT, FREE,
>                        IARG_FUNCARG_ENTRYPOINT_VALUE, 0,
>                        IARG_END);
>         RTN_Close(freeRtn);
>     }
> }
>
> /* ===================================================================== */
>
> VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v)
> {
>     TraceFile.close();
> }
>
> /* ===================================================================== */
> /* Print Help Message                                                    */
> /* ===================================================================== */
>
> INT32 Usage()
> {
>     cerr << "This tool produces a trace of calls to malloc." << endl;
>     cerr << endl << KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary() << endl;
>     return -1;
> }
>
> /* ===================================================================== */
> /* Main                                                                  */
> /* ===================================================================== */
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     // Initialize pin & symbol manager
>     PIN_InitSymbols();
>     if( PIN_Init(argc,argv) )
>     {
>         return Usage();
>     }
>
>     // Write to a file since cout and cerr maybe closed by the application
>     TraceFile.open(KnobOutputFile.Value().c_str());
>     TraceFile << hex;
>     TraceFile.setf(ios::showbase);
>
>     // Register Image to be called to instrument functions.
>     IMG_AddInstrumentFunction(Image, 0);
>     PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);
>
>     // Never returns
>     PIN_StartProgram();
>
>     return 0;
> }
>
> /* ===================================================================== */
> /* eof */
> /* ===================================================================== */
> ```
>
> The example above prints the input argument for malloc() and free(),
>   and the return value from malloc().

I tested it against my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo()
{

  int a = 2;
  int val;
  val = a;
  printf("%i\n", val);

}

int main()
{
  int i;
  char *str = (char*)malloc(15);
  char * xx = (char*)malloc(30);

  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    str[i] = rand()%23+'a';
  }
  for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    xx[i] = rand()%23+'a';
  }
  xx[i] = '\0';
  str[i] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", str);
  printf("%s\n", xx);
  free(str);
  foo();
  return 0;

}
```

And got the following output:

```
$ tail malloctrace.out 
malloc(0x110)
  returns 0x7f258b149e00
malloc(0xf)
malloc(0xf)
  returns 0x107a260
malloc(0x1e)
  returns 0x107a280
malloc(0x400)
  returns 0x107a2b0
free(0x107a260)
```

Now, in the my posted code there are a couple of `malloc` calls:

```
char *str = (char*)malloc(15);
char * xx = (char*)malloc(30);
```

But, as you can notice in the above output, couple of malloc function calls are detected:

```
malloc(0xf)
malloc(0xf)
```

I believe these correspond to `malloc(15)` (Notice, the same is not true in the case of `malloc(30)`). Could you please tell me why is this the case, also can we detect such call only once.

Objdump:

Malloc:

```
0000000000400500 <malloc@plt>:
  400500:       ff 25 2a 0b 20 00       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x200b2a]        # 601030 <malloc@GLIBC_2.2.5>
  400506:       68 03 00 00 00          push   0x3
  40050b:       e9 b0 ff ff ff          jmp    4004c0 <.plt>
```

Part of my main function:

```
  int i;
  char *str = (char*)malloc(15);
  40063a:       bf 0f 00 00 00          mov    edi,0xf
  40063f:       e8 bc fe ff ff          call   400500 <malloc@plt>
  400644:       48 89 45 f0             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rax
  char * xx = (char*)malloc(30);
  400648:       bf 1e 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1e
  40064d:       e8 ae fe ff ff          call   400500 <malloc@plt>
  400652:       48 89 45 e8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rax
```

Notice only a couple of malloc calls.

Comment: The Pin tool looks fine. Note that `malloc(0x1e)` corresponds to `malloc(30)`. I think somehow `malloc(0xf)` is being called twice. Examine the assembly code generated by your compiler using `objdump`.

Comment: Compiling your test program (not the PIN tool) with `gcc -Og` on x86-64 Linux, and tracing its library function calls with `ltrace`, I see only the expected 2 `malloc` calls.  Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `malloc` to see if there really is a 2nd call to it from somewhere?

Comment: hadi yes I examined that, @Peter yes, I debugged the code exactly as u said, but couldn't find anything (maybe I'm lacking some knowledge). I have updated the question with objdump.

Comment: Maybe try compiling with `-fno-plt`.  Perhaps lazy dynamic linking is causing the first call from within your program to be seen twice.  (Although the real malloc function in libc is only called once; the first through the PLT stub it doesn't jump directly to malloc.  Single-step into it on the first and then the 2nd call if you want to see the PLT in action.

Comment: Hmm... (1) Which Pin version are you using? (2) Which compiler & version & compiler options are you using to compile the code? (3) How are you compiling the Pin tool? I'll try to see if I can reproduce this on my system.

Comment: @peter yes I just tried what you said, but couldn't find anything unusual (again, this could be because of my limited knowledge). Hadi - 1) pin-3.7 2) Compiler: `gcc/g++-8.2.1` with no special flags. 3) For the compilation of pin, I am using the same makefile provided in `ManualExamples` folder of pin. Thanks (both of )u.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the behavior using gcc 5.4, gcc 7.3, or gcc 8.1. I only get one `malloc` call in the trace per `malloc` call.

Comment: Hadi: Thanks. I am not sure why is it happening in my case though. I tried few other examples, but still the same result. Only for the `first` malloc called. (`0xf` in the example above).

Comment: @R4444 hello, this is an old question, but did you ever figure out the reason why this problem occurred? Similar thing is happening on my code, and I was just wondering whether there is any update on this.